# Difference between @Delegate and @Mixin AST transformations in Groovy

Tags: groovy, design-patterns, abstract-syntax-tree, delegation, mixins

What's the difference between [@Delegate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Delegate.html) and [@Mixin](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Mixin.html) AST transformations in Groovy.

Maybe my question has to do with OO and when apply different patterns, but I use both and I can achieve the same behavior.

```
class Person {
    String name = "Clark"
    def walk() { "Walk" }
}

@Mixin(Person)
class Superhero {
    def fly() { "Fly" }
}

def superman = new Superhero()
assert superman.name == "Clark"
assert superman.walk() == "Walk"
assert superman.fly() == "Fly"
```

---

```
class Person {
    String name = "Clark"
    def walk() { "Walk" }
}

class Superhero {
    @Delegate Person person
    def fly() { "Fly" }
}

def superman = new Superhero(person: new Person())
assert superman.name == "Clark"
assert superman.walk() == "Walk"
assert superman.fly() == "Fly"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The behavior is similar, but `@Delegate` and `@Mixin` are implemented completely differently.

`@Delegate` generates accessor methods at compile time.  Superhero will have a method called `walk()` that simply calls `person.walk()`.  The generated methods can be seen by dumping the Superhero class file with `javap`.

`@Mixin`, on the other hand just creates a small stub that mixs in the `Person` methods at runtime.  It uses groovy's meta-object protocol to allow Superhero to respond to Person's methods.  In this case, you won't see any Person methods in `Superhero.class`.

`@Delegate` has the advantage that the methods are callable from Java and it avoids doing a dynamic invocation.  In addition, `@Mixin` can't augment the class with properties.