# what is the purpose of runtime mixins in groovy

Tags: groovy

What is the purpose of `runtime mixins` in groovy?

Mixins overall one of the ways to add functionallity to class without multiple inheritance issues. But what is its purpose in Groovy? Traits can do the same.

Annotation `@Mixin` is considered deprecated at all. Will runtime mixins have the same fate one day?

Comment: I think mixins had issues, and then traits came along as a better alternative

Comment: My understanding is the same as @tim_yates - Traits are a replacement for mixins.

Comment: I thought issues was with annotation mixins?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121890/difference-between-delegate-mixin-and-traits-in-groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, recently I found a case where using mixins helped me a lot.

```
String.metaClass {
    invokeMethod {
        String name, args ->
            System.out.println "[$name] invokation with $args"
    }
}

class GroovyInterceptableWrapper 
    implements GroovyInterceptable {
}


String.mixin(GroovyInterceptableWrapper)
```

Though again if I used there `trait` instead of class and then invoked `withTraits` I would have achieved the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime mixins give us the ability to add methods to existed classes at runtime. The important part of the answer is "existed" and "runtime". 
So, you can easily add new methods to any 3rd party library at runtime.

Comment: I can do that with categories blocks and metaclasses.

Comment: @user1432980, Metaclasses are a really "unsafe" way to perform this functionality. Categories work only for blocks of code, so they solve other problems.