# Groovy extension method with traits?

Tags: groovy, extension-methods, mixins, traits

I'd like to know if there is any way to add methods to library classes using Groovy traits.

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121890/difference-between-delegate-mixin-and-traits-in-groovy) @Mixin is used for this, or you can use the runtime mixin approach with metaclass. Since @Mixin is now [deprecated](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Mixin.html) in favor of traits, any chance to achieve the same behavior by using traits or is runtime mixin the only option?

Thank you

Comment: The Groovy documentation explains the available options very well: http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Groovy also supports implementing traits dynamically at runtime. It
>   allows you to "decorate" an existing object using a trait.

You can decorate an object, however, I am afraid that it is not possible to decorate a class so that all its instances have the method available. See below a simple example that may help you or find more details [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_implementing_a_trait_at_runtime).

```
trait Extra {
    String extra() { "I'm an extra method" }            
}

class Something {                                       
    String doSomething() { 'Something' }                
}

def s = new Something() as Extra                        

assert s.extra() == "I'm an extra method"                                               
assert s.doSomething() == 'Something'
```