# Groovy: Add references to methods in a property to a parent object

Tags: groovy

Say I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
  def doFoo() {
    println "foo"
  }
}
```

And another like this:

```
class Bar {
  def doBar() {
    println "bar"
  }
}
```

And one more that looks like this:

```
class Baz {
  Foo foo = new Foo()
  Bar bar = new Bar()
}
```

With that example, what would it take to be able to use it like this:

```
Baz baz = new Baz()
baz.doFoo()
baz.doBar()
```

where the `doFoo` and `doBar` method calls simply delegate to the defined versions in their respective objects? Is there a way to do this with some kind of metaprogramming, or am I stuck defining each method individually as a wrapper?

Comment: Found another post that goes into more detail about AST transformations and traits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23124968/493807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@Delegate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Delegate.html) is what you need:

```
class Foo {
  def doFoo() {
    println "foo"
  }
}

class Bar {
  def doBar() {
    println "bar"
  }
}

class Baz {
  @Delegate
  Foo foo = new Foo()
  @Delegate
  Bar bar = new Bar()
}

Baz baz = new Baz()
baz.doFoo()
baz.doBar()
```

Comment: Just found this myself. Still learning Groovy and loving it more every day!

Comment: @Andy, yes, it's really nice language.