# Diamond Issue with Groovy traits

Tags: groovy, traits

In many blog about Groovy Traits it's mentioned that it will solve the Diamond Problem. But the concept is not clear to me that how traits will solve the Diamond Problem.

Can any one explain please.

Answer (score 7):

The [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem#The_diamond_problem) is a problem when you have multiple inheritance and two or more super classes define one or more functions with the same signature.

With groovy traits, the behaviour is well-defined. By default, the last implementation is chosen.

```
trait A {
    String name() { "A" }
}
trait B {
    String name() { "B" }
}
class C implements A,B { }
class D implements B,A { }

assert new C().name() == "B"
assert new D().name() == "A"
```

It is also possible to choose the one you want:

```
class E implements A,B {
    String name() { A.super.name() + B.super.name() }
}

assert new E().name() == "AB"
```

Comment: Is this handled in a same way of Java 8.

Comment: Is trait resolve the  diamond issue in the same way Java 8 do. Can you confirm.

Comment: @Souvik The short answer is no, java 8 resolves this differently when you encounter the diamond problem with default implementations in interfaces. See for instance [this blog post](https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-multiple-inheritance-conflict-resolution-rules-and-diamond-problem/) for a walk-through of conflict resolution rules in java 8.